# How to create gcloud project in a folder?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I know how to create a project using gcloud command line tool.

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create DEPLOYMENT_NAME
```

But what id really like to do is create this project inside of a specific folder in gcloud. Is there a way to accomplish that?

(At this point I am hesitant to use gcloud alpha, unless it is production ready.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a project in a folder as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders#creating_a_project_in_a_folder):

```
   gcloud alpha projects create [PROJECT_ID]
      --folder [FOLDER_ID]
```

Description of GCP's launch stages including **alpha** is [here](https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages).

Comment: Thanks @savac but I am not sure about alpha. I want to have it in stabilized and production ready toolset. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think there is a way round it. I guess you can ask GCP Support about the risks of using this specific alpha feature.